# Can I make mailto: links open up in gmail instead of evolution?

Tags: gnome, evolution, email, gmail, gconf

mailto: links fire up annoying "Evolution Setup Assistant".  I want it to open a compose window in gmail in my web browser.  There are existing questions about this here, but the answers are outdated and no longer work on 11.04.

*on my system*: I'm using chromium browser, and I think the path goes like this `chrome` -> `xdg-open` -> `gnome-open` and it's evolution that is set up when I check in `gconf-editor`, so I changed that key to `gnome-open https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%U`, but it's still firing up Evolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the desktop webmail application, for instance. http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/desktop-webmail

And put the following in file `/usr/share/applications/desktop-webmail.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Desktop Webmail
GenericName=Email
Comment=Compose email in browser
Comment[de]=EMail in Browser schreiben
Exec=desktop-webmail %U
Icon=desktop-webmail
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Application;Network;Email
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Compose

[Compose Shortcut Group]
Name=Compose New Message
Exec=desktop-webmail mailto:%U
TargetEnvironment=Messaging Menu;Unity
```

Comment: this is what i used to use in 10.10 that is no longer working in 11.04.  there is no new option in `system->preferences->preferred applications` under mail reader combo box.

Comment: it doesn't work out of the box, but i have figured out how to fix it.  so i will edit your answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. This does work, after uninstalling Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of [GNOME Gmail](http://gnome-gmail.sourceforge.net/) is compatible with GNOME 3. Available at:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnome-gmail/files/

or enable the PPA referenced at:

- https://launchpad.net/~daves/+archive/daves

If you use the version in the PPA, remember that Preferred Applications is in the System Info utility now.